# Drupal 6 + Twitter Bootstrap 3 theme

Tags: 6, theming

I need help in setting up bootstrap 3 theme with Drupal 6.

With a lot of research I found that we have [BootStrap](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) module that supports D7 . Can anyone tell me how I can use Bootstrap in Drupal 6?

Comment: Given that Bootstrap requires at a minimum jQuery 1.7, I think you are going to have quite an uphill battle with using it with D6

Comment: http://www.eliotdill.com/2012/06/twitter-bootstrap-theme-for-drupal-6/
see this link its may be helpful.

Comment: @MahipalPurohit it's for bootstrap v2.3 . I am looking for including bootstrap v3

Answer (score 2):

Prerit,

I think there is indeed one custom port to BS3 and that can be used in Drupal 6. Follow post [#3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2084271#comment-8688991) to get the idea. However, this is a custom theme made by an Drupal developer and its not in the drupal's project yet.
FYI, it does support jQuery version 1.7.2 by un-setting the default jquery 1.2.6 version which intern may break some functionality in your site.
The link to the [Github Repo](https://github.com/piers-shepherd-practiceweb/Bootstrap/tree/master/bootstrap).

Personally I would suggest to use [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) or [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega) for a Drupal 6.x site.